# Número de variables no coincide con los huecos preparados PHP

Tags: php

Tengo una sentencia preparada y me salta este error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't
>   match number of fields in prepared statement in...

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
$resultado_registrar = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$resultado_registrar->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, contrasenha, nif, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, fecha_nacimiento, calle, numero, piso, provincia, concello, localidad, cod_postal, tel_fijo, tel_movil, email, acceso_ciclo, anho_inicio, grupo, repetidor) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$resultado_registrar->bind_param("ssssssisissssiiississ", $usuario_registro, $contrasenha1_registro, $nif_registro, $nombre_registro, $apellido1_registro, $apellido2_registro, $fecha_nac_registro, $calle_registro, $numero_registro, $piso_registro, $provincia_registro, $concello_registro, $localidad_registro, $cod_post_registro, $tlf_fijo_registro, $tlf_movil_registro, $email_registro, $check_acces_registro, $fecha_in_registro, $rad_gru_registro, $rad_re_registro);
$resultado_registrar->execute();
$resultado_registrar->bind_result($usuario_registro, $contrasenha1_registro, $nif_registro, $nombre_registro, $apellido1_registro, $apellido2_registro, $fecha_nac_registro, $calle_registro, $numero_registro, $piso_registro, $provincia_registro, $concello_registro, $localidad_registro, $cod_post_registro, $tlf_fijo_registro, $tlf_movil_registro, $email_registro, $check_acces_registro, $fecha_in_registro, $rad_gru_registro, $rad_re_registro);
```

No entiendo ese error si tengo 21 variables para 21 huecos. Ya probé a imprimir el valor de cada variable a ver si alguna por algún casual me estaba fallando y no, y tengo otra sentencia SELECT que funciona perfectamente, la hice siguiendo el mismo esquema.

Comment: Estas tratando de obtener que resultado de un insert? le entiendo en el caso de un select. Pero de un insert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fijate que Bind_result se utiliza para obtener un resultado de la consulta. Pero tu consulta es un insert, que no devuelve un resultado (algunas implementaciones devuelven la cantidad de filas afectadas).

No deberias usar el bind_result para nada, salvo que te devuelva un solo dato con la cantidad de filas q insertaste.